# Django migration to multiple databases

Tags: django, database-migration

I am using two databases in my django project. To handle that I have a router files:

```
class SecondDB:
    """
    A router to control all database operations on models in the
    auth application.
    """
    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
        if model._meta.app_label == 'app_in_second_db':
            return 'second_db'
        else:
            return 'default'

    def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):

        if model._meta.app_label == 'app_in_second_db':
            return 'app_in_second_db'
        else:
            return 'default'

    def allow_relation(self, obj1, obj2, **hints):
        if obj1._meta.app_label == 'app_in_second_db' or \
           obj2._meta.app_label == 'auditlog':
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def allow_migrate(self, db, app_label, model_name=None, **hints):
        if app_label == 'app_in_second_db':
            return db == 'second_db'
        else:
            return db == 'default'
```

The problem is if I run

```
$./manage.py migrate --database second_db
```

All applications in the project are migrated to second database. 
I can migrate specific app

```
./manage.py migrate app_in_second_db 0001_initial --database second_db
```

but wonder if there is some error in my router file and how to prevent accidental moving all the models to the second_db database.

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the official docs:

> **makemigrations** always creates migrations for model changes, but if **allow_migrate()** returns **False**, any migration operations for the
>   **model_name** will be silently skipped when running migrate on the db...

```
def allow_migrate(self, db, app_label, model_name=None, **hints):
    if app_label == 'app_in_second_db':
        return db == 'second_db'

    # this will prevent other apps to create their tables in 'second_db'
    if db == 'second_db':
        return False

    return None
```